# Protection against remote system compromise on binary code level

Tags: vulnerability, buffer-overflow, system-compromise

My (certainly incomplete) understanding of a remote system compromise on the binary code level is roughly:

1. A program vulnerability, such as missing input validation, is exploited to insert external shellcode into the target system.
2. Program flow is diverted to execute the shellcode, e.g. by overwriting return addresses on the call stack.
3. The attacker can now execute arbitrary code on the target system with the privileges of the compromised process.

Let's assume that system level protection mechanisms are in place, in particular:

- All data segments are non-executable
- All code segments are marked as read-only
- Code is built with hardening flags, such as stack protector, input size checking etc.

How is it still possible to obtain control of the target process (via a machine code level attack) under these conditions? How can shellcode be executed when code segments can't be modified and data segments cannot be executed?

Comment: https://sploitfun.wordpress.com/2015/05/08/bypassing-nx-bit-using-return-to-libc/